# Under ubuntu 20.04 no sound from Chromium for non-console logged in user

Tags: sound, 20.04, chromium

I tend to run two logged in user at the same time when using chromium. For years this worked correctly. With ubuntu 20.04 i'm unable to obtain sound from the non-logged in user (the user not logged into the console). Other apps like firefox, vlc, ... work fine. When checking with pavucontrol chromium never shows up under the alternative user id. I'm not sure if this is 100% specific to chromium, the new chromium sandbox under snap or something to do with pulseaudio which in itself can be painfully touchy. I do see this blib when I start chromium but not sure if it is related or related to the snap sandboxing.

```
ALSA lib conf.c:3916:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
[16836:16836:1006/171553.450433:ERROR:alsa_util.cc(204)] PcmOpen: default,No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:3916:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM plug:default
[16836:16836:1006/171553.450633:ERROR:alsa_util.cc(204)] PcmOpen: plug:default,No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use pulse-audio things now seem to work. They did work with firefox and vlc but not chromium (per this post). However sometime later after some magical update things started to work. So for now this issue is resolved for myself.